# FormsAuthentification.SetAuthCookie or FormsAuthentification.SignOut ArgumentNullException in unit tests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, forms-authentication, argumentnullexception

I am writing unit tests for ASP.NET MVC 3 app that was actually not designed to have a tests, but they should be done.
One of the tests should cover login actions.
Basically what it does is sets an auth cookie. But in unit test it just fails with this thing:
`at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)
   at System.Web.Configuration.HttpCapabilitiesBase.CapsParseBool(String capsKey)
   at System.Web.Configuration.HttpCapabilitiesBase.get_Cookies()
   at System.Web.Security.CookielessHelperClass.UseCookieless(HttpContext context, Boolean doRedirect, HttpCookieMode cookieMode)
   at System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(String userName, Boolean createPersistentCookie, String strCookiePath)
   at System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(String userName, Boolean createPersistentCookie)`

I have mocked everything that can be mocked with this method below plus I set a real HttpContext, because app just fails in some places, basically it just requires real context.

```
public void SetContext(Controller controller) {

        var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
        var user = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("test"), new string[0]);

        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.User).Returns(user);

        request.Setup(r => r.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());
        request.Setup(r => r.Form).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
        request.Setup(q => q.QueryString).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
        response.Setup(r => r.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());

        var rctx = new RequestContext(context.Object, new RouteData());
        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(rctx, controller);

    }
```

What am i missing? Read everything about it, nothing really helps. To turn off cookies by setting `{"cookies", "false"}` property for Browser just solves aftermath but not the reason

Comment: It uses `context.Request.Browser.Cookies` to understand does browser supports cookie or not. Then it will try to load this information from browser capabilities file based on user agent. As for me you can try 1. to specify cookieless mode in the config. 2. mock UserAgent too from Request

Comment: Nothing changed when i changed useragent for real request, not moqed. If i mock it - other parts of app fail, so this will not help. If i set cookiless mode in the config, how could i check cookie? The point is to do that basically.

Comment: If you set `cookieless="UseCookies"` in the web.config `forms` section , then it won't try to detect browser capabilities, and will use Cookies. Otherwise it will try to detect it, and fail in your case.

Comment: same thing... this is so frustrating